# RTSP in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, video, red5, rtmp, rtsp

We are currently working on a Flex application that needs to connect to a set a traffic detection cameras via RTSP. Being totally new to the world of video streaming in general, I was wondering if that is possible.

AFAIK it is not possible to consume an RTSP feed in the Flash player, so I'm thinking that we would need some sort of a converter on the server that takes the RTSP stream and converts it to RTMP so we can consume the feed in our Flex app. We were hoping that Red5 could helps us do that.

Am I correct in my assumption and has anyone done this?

Answer (score 2):

Wowza Media seems to support RTSP to RTMF converting: http://www.wowzamedia.com/comparison.html

And there is also general video stream transcoder Xuggle http://www.xuggle.com/ based on Red5 and FFMPEG.

Answer (score 1):

You could try restreaming it via Red5 and connecting your Flex app to the Red5 server.

Read more at: http://red5wiki.com/wiki/SteamStream

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this work](http://blog.gnanet.net/2008/05/09/rtsp-source-mp4-flv-streaming/)
I tried to convert a H264 signal to a SWF stream that could be
easily be displayed in Flash. Here is the recipe. (This recipe is
for Linux.)

1. Download Live555 streaming media, from http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/
   The src file you have is usually named live555-latest.tar.gz
2. Unpack and compile:

   - Unpack:`tar xzvf live555-latest.tar.gz`. This will create a directory named live.
   - `cd live`
   - `./genMakefiles linux` (if you have a 32 bit system) or `./genMakefiles linux-64bit` if your system is 64-bit)
   - `make`, and after a while you'll have a brand new compiled code
3. Live55 has a lot of good stuff, but we are only interested in the "testProgs"
   directory, where openRTSP resides. OpenRTSP will let us receive a signal and send it
   to ffmpeg, a program wich feeds ffserver. Ffserver is a server that receives
   the signal from ffmpeg and converts it to SWF (and other formats).
4. Download, unpack, configure and install ffmpeg

   - Download ffmpeg from http://www.ffmpeg.org/. The version I tested is 0.6.1: http://www.ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-0.6.1.tar.gz
   - Unpack:`tar xzvf ffmpeg-0.6.1.tar.gz`. This will create a directory named ffmpeg-0.6.1
   - `cd ffmpeg-0.6.1`
   - All the funny video streaming things are packaged in VideoLan. So you
     better install VideoLan right now. Go to http://www.videolan.org/ and see how easy is to
     install it. You may be surprised that the package dependencies contains ffmpeg libraries.
   - After installing VideoLan do `./configure` and then `make`.
   - After 3 or 4 hours you will have mmpeg and mmserver compiled and working.
5. Now we are almost ready to stream the whole world. First of all, let's try to
   get openRTSP working.
6. Go to your "live" directory (remember 3.2) and do: cd testProgs
7. Try this:`./openRTSP -v -c -t rtsp://<hostname>:<port>/<cam_path>` First of
   all, you'll see logs which says something like:

   ```
   - opening conection blah blah.
   - sending DESCRIBE blah blah.
   - receiving streamed data.
   ```

   If all goes OK, your console will start to print a lot of strange characters very quickly.
   These characters are bytes of video, but you can't see it (now). If you don't see your screen
   printing characters, there is something wrong with your configuration. Check the steps up
   to now.
8. We got the signal! Now let's send it to an useful component: ffmpeg, which is bound to
   ffserver. We need to create a configuration file for ffserver.
9. Use your favorite editor to create this text file:

   ```
   Port 8090
   BindAddress 0.0.0.0
   MaxHTTPConnections 2000
   MaxClients 1000
   MaxBandwidth 1000
   CustomLog -
   NoDaemon

   <Feed feed1.ffm>
   File /tmp/feed1.ffm
   FileMaxSize 200K
   ACL allow 127.0.0.1
   </Feed>

   <Stream testFlash.swf>
   Feed feed1.ffm
   Format swf
   VideoFrameRate 25
   VideoSize 352x288
   VideoIntraOnly
   NoAudio
   </Stream>

   <Stream stat.html>
   Format status
   ACL allow localhost
   ACL allow 192.168.0.0 192.168.255.255
   </Stream>
   ```

   Name the file, for example, ffserver.conf. Save it anywhere, for example in the same directory of ffserver.

   So, ffserver will be bound to the port 8090, for input and output. `<Feed>` tag configures the
   input stream. The name of the configured feed in this case is feed1.ffm. Remember it for step 14.
   `<Stream>` contains configuration for the output stream. In this case the name will be testFlash.swf (remember too), and the format will be SWF. The video frame rate will be 25 and the size 352x288, and it won't contain audio. The last stream is a HTML file (stat.html) that will show you the status of the server.
10. Start `ffserver: ./ffserver -f ffserver.conf` (or wherever you have left the config file). The -f parameter indicated
    that you will load the confugration from a custom file.
11. Open a navigator and go to `http://localhost:8090/stat.html`. A status page of the server will show up, and we'll see a line of information about our testFlash.swf stream. It seems very quiet now, so let's feed this stream with the output of openRTSP (from step 7).
12. Do this:

    ```
    <path to openRTSP>/openRTSP -v -c -t rtsp://<hostname>:<port>/<cam_path> | <path to ffmeg>/ffmpeg -i - http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm
    ```

    The first path (before the "|" is the same as step 9. "|" is a symbol that connects the output of
    openRTSP (the sequence of video signal, aka strage chars) to be the input of ffmpeg. "-I -" means that
    the input of mmpeg is taken from the pipe "|" and `http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm` is the destination (output)
    of ffmpeg, wich is basically the input of ffserver.

    So with this command we have connected openRTSP -> ffmpeg -> ffserver

    When you enter this command a lot of information will be shown. Is important to note that the input params
    and the output params are shown, and these params NEED to be "compatible". In my case, this will be shown:

    ```
    Input #0, h264, from 'pipe: ':
    Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: h264, yuv420p, 352x288, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 50 tbc
    Output #0, ffm, to 'http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm':
    Metadata:
    encoder: Lavf52.64.2
    Stream #0.0: Video: FLV, yuv420p, 352x288, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 1000k tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream mapping:
    Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
    </pre>
    ```

    And then the stream begins to play. You will see in the last line numbers CONSTANTLY changing,
    telling you the live frame rating in each moment. Something like

    ```
    frame= 395 fps= 37 q=31.7 Lsize = 1404kB time=15.80 bitrate = 727.9kbits/s
    ```

    If you don't see this line of metrics, then there is something wrong with your output configuration. Go back and change the parameters of testFlash.swf.
13. Everything is done. You can see the video in `http://localhost:8090/testFlash.swf`. You can use this URL to embed a Flash movie or, as in my case, a Flex application.

Answer (score 0):

Red5 is fine, especially now with xuggle support (allows for off the shelf integration of FFMPEG) which provides great integration with red5 (ie. great tutorial on doing live stream conversion etc).

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with programming in flex or whatever it takes to bring it into a swf, then you could try and implement rtsp-over-tcp, AFAIK udp isn't available in flash.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this with Wowza.
Input was RTSP stream from Etrovision H264 DVS.
Take a look at this tread and use Application.xml file from there if you want to try it: 
http://96.30.11.104/forums/showthread.php?p=24806

Video is playing in Flash player, but the price is 5 seconds delay for a single stream, all equipment in office LAN, server running at Core2Duo/2.8GHz/3GB RAM.
Not sure if it can go faster or it's the expected transcoding damage for this setup...

Answer (score 0):

While its public / open source version is a bit dated now, you can have a look at this project which did RTSP and Image based camera transcoding into RTMP streams with Xuggler and Red5.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/imux/

(disclaimer: I worked for the company that created the original source)

Comment: LOL. I'm actually part of the team/company for which IMUX was created ;-) Good catch!